# Is there any relationship between an orderer and network organizations in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can orderer order any transaction come to it irrespective of the organization from which it is coming?

Or is there any relationship which defines that this particular orderer can order tx only for the mentioned organizations?

In the below screenshot why certificates of org1 peer and org2 peer required to create an orderer container? Is it defining some relationship between them?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, orderer can order any transaction coming to it irrespective of the organization from which it is coming. Actually it depends on genesis block. Genesis block contains the information of consortium of organizations, that you mentioned in your configtx.yaml file while creating genesis block. So, orderer can order any  transaction, coming from any organization of consortium.

Orderer share transaction/block data with other orderer containers as well. If you are running your network over TLS, then you have to mention other orderers certificate, so that it may use it for handshaking while sharing the data.